# Gmail: Image Signature "Images are not displayed" Issue

Tags: gmail

In my specific gmail account, when emails were sent, recipient will receive. 
The problem is for the recipient to see the signature, he/she must click "**Display Images Below**"

Is there any way to make that automatically appearing?

That's all,
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment, you can't set Gmail to display all images from any sender; you must do this on a per-contact basis.

source: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8833